# Is necessary to use an ID to all html elements?

Tags: html

As a HTML5 beginner, I would like to know if it is necessary to use an ID for all html elements I use ?

Comment: No. It is not necessary. It is an optional [HTML attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
  You might need to use it,when you need to work with it like ->

1. To link to an element with a specified id within a page
2. To style text with CSS

Comment: Thank you. So, I will not use id when I don't want to do something specific with this element.

Comment: Yes.This is the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, you only need to use an ID if you want to target that element or its children for style or script purposes.